# div class is blocking the middle of the video

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, css-transitions

What is the reason why I can't click on the video as the two sides are opening and how do I fix that?

Also, why is the video not centered in the middle, what will work to fix that?

https://jsfiddle.net/ugf7tkn1/

How it works is, you click on the play image and it opens up.

As the 2 sides are opening the video can't be clicked on for some reason.

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".jacketa");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  "use strict";

  let player

  const tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100); // percent
  }
  let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }

  function addPlayer(video) {
    const playlist = "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g";
    new YT.Player(video, {

      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
        controls: 1,
        loop: 1,
        rel: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        fs: 0,
        disablekb: 1,
        playlist
      },
      events: {
        "onReady": onPlayerReady,
        "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const frameContainer = document.querySelector(".video");
  videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
  display: block !important;
}

.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
  left: -500%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 500%;
}

.video-wrapper {
  min-width: 40%;
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}


.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide ">
        <div class="video-wrapper">
          <div class="ratio-keeper">

            <div class="border ">
              <div class="video video-frame"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the div with the class 'split-wrap' is blocking the middle of the video. it needs to be removed ao you can click the centre of the video

Comment: Do you know of a way where it can stay?

Comment: you can unset split-wrap div's position on click of play icon. Using below:
document.querySelector(".split-wrap").style.position = "unset";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `split-wrap` overlays on the video container, hence we can't click the center of the video. While the curtains open, we can apply `pointer-events: none` to be able to click the play button on the video i.e. the center of the video.
2. I have used `top` property to vertically align the video container, by first giving its parent container `height: 100%`.

Code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sh9c0x8/1/)

Comment: Which class would pointer-events: none; be put on?

Comment: On class `split-wrap`. You can see the change in function `coverClickHandler` (see its first two lines).

Comment: But then it is not clickable, the play image. https://jsfiddle.net/omcgds56/

Comment: This is why the property is applied while the curtains are opening.  Handle this via javascript (as is done in the fiddle).